# Java Socket Constructor, Socket(String hostName, int port), Hangs

Tags: java, linux, sockets, ubuntu

I'm trying to make a simple client/server program.  I have opened a ServerSocket, but can't seem to connect to it with the client socket I've created.

I've been looking for an answer for a while now - frankly, I'm not exactly sure what to even search for with this problem.

Here's the client code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

Socket s = null;


try{
    System.out.println("connecting to host...");
    s = new Socket("dagobah", 6464);
}catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    System.err.println("Can't connect");
    System.exit(1);
}
System.out.println("Connected to host");


s.close();
}
```

}

Here's the server code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class server{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{


ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
try{
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6464);
}catch (IOException e){
    System.err.println("fail to start server");
    System.exit(1);
}
System.out.println("Server started : )");



Socket clientSocket = null;
try{
    System.out.println("waiting for a client...");
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("fail can't accept client connection");
    System.exit(-1);
}
System.out.println("client connected");


clientSocket.close();
serverSocket.close();
}
```

}

The client never makes it past the try block

client output: connecting to host...

server output: Server started : )
               waiting for a client...

Since posting this question, I have learned that this is a problem specific to my computer.  I'm running Linux 2.6.38-11-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux Ubuntu Natty

Any and all help will be much appreciated! : )

Comment: a side note, close the sockets inside a finally block, or -if you are using Java 7- use try-with-resources.
And if you have to use `System.exit(-1);`, do that after the finally block to make sure the sockets gets closed.

Comment: what is `dagobah` in your code? Is it the name of the server??

Answer (score 5):

The `Socket` constructor does not actually connect, but it does try to resolve the host name into an IP address. It looks like in this case the name resolution is taking a long time, and would eventually time out, throwing an `UnknownHostException`. I've heard this can take minutes on Windows.

How is `dagobah` resolved, by DNS or? Try using the IP address instead of the name.

Comment: Joni, thanks for the help!  Yes, you're right, it eventually times out.  And 'dagobah' is the hostname of my computer, so ... I don't believe it uses DNS.  I tried to enter the loopback address by using InetAddress.getHostByName(null) but this only gives the same results.

Comment: You could use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` instead. The name resolution of the local host name depends on the operating system. On Unix you would configure it in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Could you take a full thread dump with `jstack` when the program hangs? That way we see where exactly it happens. A debugger would also work.

Answer (score 5):

You have a problem with the Socket constructor. Check how you are trying to resolve `dagobah` to an IP address. Try your code with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

I tried and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried both localhost and 127.0.0.1 ... neither one will connect.  It's good to know this works on another computer, though.  I guess I'll move to a different machine : /

Answer (score 3):

Try to replace your line

```
s = new Socket("dagobah", 6464);
```

with

```
s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6464);
```

That might can solve your query. Seems like your dagobah is really not your HostName as indicated by you. Do recheck that, by Right Clicking your My Computer and go to Properties, and find the name under Computer Name. The above line will solve the issue for you.

Comment: Hmm... it still seems to hang.  Also, chris@dagobah:~/$ hostname
dagobah

Comment: @Chris : Then try to provide a new port, might be that port is busy already.